# Why is System.Net.Mail getting an "authentication failure" and System.Web.Mail doesn't?

Tags: .net, smtp

I'm sending an email from an asp.net application via a 3rd party SMTP server. This server requires authentication. Generally I would use System.Net.Mail combined with System.Net.NetworkCredential to accomplish this.

In this particular case I keep getting an "authentication failed" message. I know the hostname, username, and password information is correct; I've successfully sent messages via Outlook.

I finally resorted to using System.Web.Mail to send the message and used System.Web.Mail.MailMessage.Fields.Add to specifiy the credentials.

Looking at the transmissions in Wireshark, I've noticed a slight difference in the initial AUTH command. Both Outlook and System.Web.Mail send "AUTH LOGIN" where System.Net.Mail sends "AUTH LOGIN bWFpba==".

After searching a bit, I've found others have the similar problems, but usually the fix is to use an intermediate relay server. I thought I'd post the question here to see if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: Check the workaround posted to this feedback report: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/212467/530-authentication-required-error-with-some-smtp-servers

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the System.Net.Mail version is sending a Hash or Challenge of some type while the System.Web.Mail version is not. Is there a setting that you are using in one that you are not using in another? Alternatively, it could be that setting the NetworkCredential assumes you want to use a Hashed or Encrypted mechanism for communication while the server you are sending to may not support that.